# Return multiple values from a function in hash

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have created a function which essentially logs into a router,executes a command, parses the command output and prints the `Peer status`  and `Peer ip`
Function returns the values as expected. In addition to status and peer ip if i want to return 3 more values say for eg:  $session_id, $session_state and $time. How do I do that with hash ? I want the function to return all the five values in a Hash.

```
sub session_status {
    my ($self,$interface_name)  = @_;
    my $status  = 0;
    my $peer_ip = 0;

    #command to chek the status
    my $cmd     = 'show crypto session interface ' . $interface_name;
    $self->_login();
    my $tunnel_status = $self->exec($cmd);

    #Regex to match the 'tunnel status' and 'peer ip' string in the cmd output

    foreach my $line (  $tunnel_status ) {
      if ( $line =~ m/Session\s+status:\s+(.*)/ ) {
            $status = $1;
      }
      if ( $line =~ m/Peer:\s+(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)/ ) {
            $peer_ip = $1;
      }
    }
    return ($status,$peer_ip);
}
```

Function call:

```
 my ($tunnel_status, $peer_ip) = $sshobject->session_status("Tunnel1");
     print "TUNNEL STATUS : $tunnel_status\n";
     print "PEER IP : $peer_ip\n";
```

output :

```
TUNNEL STATUS : DOWN
PEER IP : 100.81.1.42
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return { 'status' => $status, 'peer_ip' => $peer_ip,
    'session_id' => $session_id, 'session_state' => $session_state,
    'time' => $time };
```

And then you can do this:

```
my $stuff = $sshobject->session_status("Tunnel1");
print "TUNNEL STATUS : $stuff->{'status'}\n";
print "PEER IP : $stuff->{'peer_ip'}\n";
# etc
```

Comment: How do i define the hash in the function ?

Comment: @virat Martin already gave you all you need (+1 for that!): His return statement returns a reference to an anonymous hash with 5 key/value pairs. Like you returned a list `(...)` without explicitly defining it, he returned a hashref without explicitly defining it.